# Shattering of a set of binary classifiers

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, machine-learning

Let $S$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{F}_{S}=\{f:S\to\{-1,+1\}\}$ be a set of different label assignments. Show that $\mathcal{F}_{S}$ shatters at least $|\mathcal{F}_{S}|$ subsets of $S$.

Here is what I attempted. Consider all maximum shattered subsets of $S$, denoted as $\{S_1,S_2,\cdots, S_{n}\}$, these subsets are maximum shattered in a sense that they can be shattered by $\mathcal{F}_{S}$ but any other subset not in $\{S_1,S_2,\cdots, S_{n}\}$ that includes any subset in $\{S_1,S_2,\cdots, S_{n}\}$ cannot be shattered. So the number of subsets of $S$ shattered by $\mathcal{F}_{S}$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{|S_{i}|}-(n-1)$. We also know that for any element $x\in S\setminus(\cup_{i=1}^{n}S_{i})$, $f(x)$ has the same value for all $f\in \mathcal{F}_{S}$ otherwise $\{x\}$ should be a new shattered set and $x$ should be in $\cup_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$. So the next question is to prove $|\mathcal{F}_{S}|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{|S_{i}|}-(n-1)$, and this is the part I don't know how to prove. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use induction on $|\mathcal{F}_S|$? Take some $x \in S$ such that $\{x\}$ is shattered by $\mathcal{F}_S$. Let $\mathcal{F}_S^-,\mathcal{F}_S^+$ be the subsets of $\mathcal{F}_S$ that assign $-,+$ to $x$, respectively. Etc..

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437806/shattering-of-a-set-of-binary-classifiers

Comment: This is a well-known lemma, usually assigned as homework.